# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type HistoricalData from Object value JsonToken.START_OBJECT

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

Iam triying to call external API from SpringBoot, once i recive the response im trying to save in a dto Object.

```
 HistoricalApiResponse responseMap = restTemplate.getForObject(
                url,
                HistoricalApiResponse.class);
```

sample response in below formate

```
{
"personsData": {
    "2023-02-27": [
    
        {
            "country": "INDIA",
            "age": 19,
            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
        },
        
        {
            "country": "UK",
            "age": 29,
            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
        }
        
    ],
    "2023-02-25": [
    
        {
            "country": "JPY",
            "age": 39,
            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
        },
        
        
        {
            "country": "CHINA",
            "age": 39,
            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

}

I have wrote HistoricalApiResponse class in below formate.

```java
public class HistoricalApiResponse {
    HistoricalData[] historicalData;
}

class HistoricalData{
     List<Person> personsData;
}

class Person{
    Integer age;
    String country;
    Date upatedAt;

}
```

Im getting below exception
Cannot deserialize value of type `[LHistoricalData;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `[LHistoricalData;` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

I have tried by changing HistoricalData to list, map and other ways. but getting some other exception. Im not able to find excat java class for above response.

Can you guys please help what's the Structure of Response class for the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your java class is not matching the json model. You need a "personData" object which looks like a map where the keys are *Date* objects and the values are *List*. This is how it worked for me:

```java
public class HistoricalApiResponse {
    public Map<Date, List<Person>> personsData;
}

public class Person {
    public Integer age;
    public String country;
    @JsonProperty("updated_at") // needed for mapping
    public Date upatedAt;
}
```

And here's how you can test it:

```java
@Test
void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String json = """
            {
                "personsData": {
                    "2023-02-27": [
                        {
                            "country": "INDIA",
                            "age": 19,
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "country": "UK",
                            "age": 29,
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
                        }
                    ],
                    "2023-02-25": [
                        {
                            "country": "JPY",
                            "age": 39,
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "country": "CHINA",
                            "age": 39,
                            "updated_at": "2022-06-24T00:00:11.483Z"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
            """;

    var om = new ObjectMapper();
    HistoricalApiResponse response = om.readValue(json, HistoricalApiResponse.class);
    
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Comment: Please do not suggest using `java.util.Date`. There are several alternatives that are far better. `LocalDate` would be better for the key, and the `updated_at` could use `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` depending on need.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Thanks for pointing it out. I agree completely. No one should use `Date` since Java 8. `Instant` is the correct type for `updatedAt`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. yes, i agree, java.util.Date is not a good choice. However, I have just shown how this json can easily be mapped to a java model. The field can be a Date, a LocalDateTime, an Instant, a String, or the whole class can be implemented differently altogether (instead of using a map). These decisions are up to the developer and I consider them out of the scope of this about the jackson mapping issue.